# JGit get timezone of a commit

Tags: git, jgit

In JGit, how to get timezone of a commit?
Current RevCommit class does not have anything about timezone.
It only returns UTC unix time

Comment: Why do you assume the timezone is stored in the commit? Especially when, as you say, the time is stored in UTC?

Comment: Yes, timezone is also stored in a commit object. Can you see "-0700" in http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Commit-Objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PersonIdent:

```java
RevCommit commit = ...;
PersonIdent committerIdent = commit.getCommitterIdent();
if (committerIdent != null) {
    TimeZone timeZone = committerIdent.getTimeZone(); // or getTimeZoneOffset()
}
```

There is also `getAuthorIdent()` which is the same for author.